# On weak linear continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

This is what I have first asked in SE but  I think it is more suitable for here. I am interested in the set of all continuous functions  $f: (0, \infty) \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$   with the following property:

**For any irrational positive number $\alpha$ there exists a real number $b_\alpha$ 
such that for any $x > 0 $ we have $f(\alpha x) = b_\alpha f(x)$.**

Any reference or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of information would you like? Where did this come up? It will be hard to say anything unless you provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

$f$ must be a power function, $f(x)= cx^e$. Proof:

Assume $f(x) \neq 0$ for some $x$, Then $b_\alpha= f(\alpha x)/f(x)$ for all $\alpha$, hence $b_\alpha$ is a continuous function $(0,\infty)-\mathbb Q^{>0} \to \mathbb R$.

$b_{\alpha \beta} = f(\alpha \beta x)/f(x) = b_\alpha f(\beta x)/f(x)= b_\alpha b_\beta$. Hence  $b_\alpha$ is a continuous group homomorphism.

We can adapt the usual proof that any continuous group homomorphism $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is linear to a proof that $b_\alpha$ is a power function $x \to x^c$. Hence $f(x) = c x^e$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: what is the domain of $b_\alpha$?

Comment: Irrational positive numbers. But we can easily extend it to all positive numbers.